# Website created but shows an Unsecure message

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I have just learnt to create a website and built one for my art. I am hosting it using 000webhost.com.

After I upload my files and navigate to my website, in the address bar, I see a shield with a cross mark and the message "This page is trying to load scripts from unauthenticated sources."

How do I resolve this issue? I do have images of my art on the website but I dont have any JS files, only HTML, CSS and PHP.

Comment: your website URL ?

Comment: Probably some JS 000webhost.com is using for ads or tracking on your site.

Comment: Also make sure you're using relative file paths rather than absolute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are accessing your website via https protocol. In this case all images, css and other embedded resources should be loaded via https too. 
Use a developer tool like chrome developer toolbar or firebug to find out which resources are causing the error: you will see a red warning message complaining about data loaded over http. Move those resources to https to fix the warning.